# center (subscene) of borderpane not resizing

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making an application that uses a SubScene instance on the BorderPane center, and on the right side i want to put a vbox with some content. The subscene starts with the correct size, and resizes perfectly when maximizing the window. [before maximizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOK4h.png), [maximized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJNn6.png)

The problem is, when minimizing the window this happens:
[minimized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTbvA.png)

What can I do?

Here's how I managed the resizing system:

```
SubScene subScene = new SubScene(group, 1200, 700, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);  
HBox centerBox = new HBox();

subScene.widthProperty().bind(centerBox.widthProperty());
subScene.heightProperty().bind(centerBox.heightProperty());

centerBox.getChildren().add(subScene);
```

Comment: If this is not a 3D and 2D project I would recommend against `SubScene`. I think it should still work though.

Comment: Post working code that will reproduce the problem. Only do the layout components.

Comment: @Sedrick When I was updating the post with code that reproduces the problem(without child nodes), the error disappeared... how can a 3dnode interfere on resizing in such way?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same problem. I [solved it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l8PE.png) by binding the SubScene width and height properties with the scene's, and then subtracting the width(200) and height(75) of adjacent nodes:

```
    //  Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 800, true);
    //  SubScene subScene = new SubScene(group, 1200, 700, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
    //  centerBox is an instance of HBox

    subScene.widthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().subtract(200));
    subScene.heightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty().subtract(75));
    centerBox.getChildren().add(subScene);
```